# CloudSQL - Export data - Using google-api-services-sqladmin - v1beta4

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I'm new to cloudSQL, trying to build a small console application to test the functionalities of CLoudSQL API. **(google-api-services-sqladmin - v1beta4)**

Can somebody help me to get start with some sample code?

For example, i want to export data from cloudSQL to GCS using - select query?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample HTTP request that will export the table `mysql.user` to a CSV file in Cloud Storage:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/<project>/instances/<instance>/export
content-type: application/json
content-length: <length-of-request-body>
Authorization: Bearer <access-token>

{
  "exportContext": {
    "csvExportOptions": {
      "selectQuery": "SELECT * FROM mysql.user"
     },
   "uri": "gs://<bucket>/users.csv",
   "fileType": "CSV"
  }
}
```

Note that you need to set the values for `<project>`, `<instance>`, `<access-token>`, and `<bucket>`.

Once you have those parameters, you can easily try this either using the [API Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/export), at the bottom where it says "try it".

Or simply by using `curl`:

CURL command:

```
$ curl -X POST \
  https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/<project>/instances/<instance>/export \
  -H'content-length: <length-of-request-body>'
  -H'content-type: application/json'
  -H'Authorization: Bearer <access-token>'
  -d'{"exportContext": {"csvExportOptions": {"selectQery": "SELECT * FROM mysql.user"}, "fileType": "CSV", "uri": "gs://<bucket>/users.csv"}}'
```